# Convert inline links to reference links in pure JS?

Tags: javascript

How could I convert

```
Text with inline source one [https://example.com/]. Text with inline source two [https://example.com/example].
```

to

```
Text with inline source one[1]. Text with inline source two[2]
[1] https://example.com/
[2] https://example.com/example
```

I've tried things like

```
var all=document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
links=all.outerHTML.match(/\[http.+?\]/g);
for(i=1;links.length;i++){
    all.outerHTML.replace(/\[http.+?\]/,'<a class="reflink" href="#'+i+'">['+i+']</a>';)
    bottomRefs+='['+i+1+'] '+links[i];
}
```

and many variations, but I'm out of ideas. Any help would be appreciated.

Beyond that, how could I also allow for repeated links referencing the 1st instance of it (e.g. example.com appears again in link number 15 but it would reference it as [1] since it's repeated)? But that adds a lot of complexity so even a JQuery or similar solution would be appreciated.

Comment: That loop should be `for (var i=0; i<links.length; i++)`

Answer (score 0):

**Part #1:** Find and replace links with numbers.

```js
let element = document.querySelector('p');
let result = element.innerText;

// regex to find the links containing "http(s):// inside []
let regex = /\[https?\:\/\/(.*?)\]/g; 

let match;
let counter = 0;

while ((match = regex.exec(element.innerText)) !== null) {
    counter++
    // match[0] is the full match like "[https://example.com/]"
    // string replace and concatenate the needed parts
    result  = result.replace(match[0], `[${counter}]`); 
    result += `\n[${counter}] ${match[0]}`
}

// replace the text with the result
element.innerText = result;
```

```html
<p>Text with inline source one [https://example.com/]. Text with inline source two [https://example.com/example].</p>
```

**Part #2:** Use same numbers if same link. Use an array to push the found links if they are not already stored in array. Like that you can then retrieve the "index" from the array containig the position of the needed link.

```js
let element = document.querySelector('p');
let result = element.innerText;

let foundLinks = [];

// regex to find the links containing "http(s):// inside []
let regex = /\[https?\:\/\/(.*?)\]/g; 

let match;

while ((match = regex.exec(element.innerText)) !== null) {
    let isNewLink = false;
    
    // match[0] is the full match like "[https://example.com/]"
    // if the link is not inside foundLinks add it to the array
    if(false === foundLinks.includes(match[0])) {
        isNewLink = true;
        foundLinks.push(match[0]);
    }
    
    let indexOfMatch = foundLinks.indexOf(match[0])
    // string replace and concatenate the needed parts
    result  = result.replace(match[0], `[${indexOfMatch+1}]`);
    
    if (isNewLink) {
        result += `\n[${indexOfMatch+1}] ${match[0]}`
    }
}

// replace the text with the result
element.innerText = result;
```

```html
<p>Text with inline source one [https://example.com/]. Text with inline source two [https://example.com/example]. same link as first link [https://example.com/].</p>
```

With multiple `<p>` tags you can do like so:

```js
let elements = document.querySelectorAll('p');
let foundLinks = [];
let allLinksText = '\n';

// regex to find the links containing "http(s):// inside []
let regex = /\[https?\:\/\/(.*?)\]/g; 

elements.forEach( (element, index) => {
  let elementContent = element.innerText;
  let match;
  while ((match = regex.exec(element.innerText)) !== null) {
    let isNewLink = false;

    // match[0] is the full match like "[https://example.com/]"
    // if the link is not inside foundLinks add it to the array
    if(false === foundLinks.includes(match[0])) {
      isNewLink = true;
      foundLinks.push(match[0]);
      allLinksText += `\n[${foundLinks.indexOf(match[0])+1}] ${match[0]}`
    }
    // string replace and concatenate the needed parts
    elementContent = elementContent.replace(match[0], `[${foundLinks.indexOf(match[0])+1}]`);
  }

  element.innerText = elementContent;
  if(index === elements.length-1) {   // if last item
    element.innerText += allLinksText // append list of links
  }
});
```

```html
<p>Text with inline source one [https://example.com/]. Text with inline source two [https://example.com/example]. same link as first link [https://example.com/].</p>
<p>Text with inline source one [https://example.com/]. Text with inline source two [https://example.com/example]. same link as first link [https://example.com/].</p>
<p>Bla [https://hello-world.com/] i one [https://example.com/]. Text with inline source two [https://example.com/example]. [https://hello-world.com/] same link as first link [https://example.com/].</p>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for that, you're a star! However for some reason it says "Uncaught TypeError: element is null", and doing `alert(document.querySelector('p'));` confirms it returns null! What could be going on?? In any case I should've put more than 1 `<p>` tag in the example text, as it's for processing many `<p>` tags. What's the most efficient way to change it (part 2) to `document.querySelectorAll('p')` and then looping for every `element[i]`?

Comment: @cryptofree where do you place all the links? after each `<p>` tag? or one list of links at the very end for all `<p>` tags?